# Access property of 'singleton' class PHP

Tags: php, singleton, instance, multiple-instances

I am not sure whether the technique I use is appropriate or not.
I have a class, singleton, with a subinstance like this:

```
final class Singleton {

    public $subinstance;
    private static $instance = NULL;

    private function __construct() {
        $this->subinstance = new subinstance(); 
    }

   public static function getInstance() {

       if (NULL === self::$instance) {
           self::$instance = new self;
       }

   return self::$instance;

   }

   private function __clone() {}
}
```

And now if I want to access the subinstance from outside the class in another class, I do:

```
$s = singleton::getInstance();
$s->subinstance->....
```

Is this the right way to do this?
And what happens when I do `$s=singleton::getInstance();`, does the entire singleton class gets copied into $s or is this more like a pointer?

Comment: I am currently looking into singleton behaviors and learned that singleton classes do not execute the '__construct()' function unless an object is created from it (getInstance() in this case). Also the properties cannot be accessed in singleton unless  they are declared static (or an object created out of it). I am leaving this comment here so that others won't spend as much time as I have in realizing this. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is fine, although in your example code I'm assuming you meant to write:

```
$s = Singleton::getInstance(); // with the S capitalized
```

When you call the getInstance method, the class is looking to see if a version of itself has already been instantiated.  If it has, it will return a reference to that instance instead of creating an entirely new instance.  If the instance has not been created yet, it will create the instance and then return a reference to it.

I'm not sure why sixeightzero has stated that you shouldn't instantiate a class in the constructor of your instance.  You shouldn't experience any issues when doing so.

Comment: The way of doing this is fine. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you do $a = singleton, $a will be a reference to the singleton class. Any changes in $a will reflect in access by singleton:: etc.. (pointer)

Why are you doing a subinstance in the constructor? This can cause issues, and should create a method to handle the subinstance outside the constructor inside a protected method. What does your subinstance look like?